# Mesibo On Premise Error loading certificates

Tags: mesibo

Im following the mesibo tutorial to setup an on-premise instance, but when i try to configure the TLS Certificate it gives me this error.

```
E1108-111819-240 (17): Loading certificates from: /certs
**CRITICAL**1108-111819-240 (17): Unable to load certificate: /certs/cert.pem
E1108-111819-244 (17): Checking with letsencrypt.org for the certificate validity
E1108-111819-424 (17): Found a valid letsencrypt certificate
```

When the mesibo api tries to connect to the websocket, it shows this error:
error: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: IP: xxxx is not in the cert's list:

I have verified that the cert.pem certificate is correct and can be read by openssl